# R ggplot2 Warning Message: Removed rows containing non-finite values

Tags: r, ggplot2

R Version:4.2.2

R Studio Version:2022.07.2 Build 576

Windows Version: Windows 11 Home, 22H2

I'm using the data "flights" in "nycflights13" package. I add 2 variables "cancel_status" and "sche_dep_exact_time", and trying to make a plot with geom_boxplot, but R always automatically remove the cases that cancel_status is "Y". I don't know why.

I have checked the posts that with the same "removed rows containing non-finite values" problem, every post suggest that there's a limit in the code, so the r will remove the cases out of the limit, but I didn't see any limit in my case.

Code to add Variable:

```
`flights_cancel_status <- flights %>%
  mutate(cancel_status = ifelse(is.na(dep_time), "Y", "N"), 
         sche_dep_hour = dep_time %/% 100,
         sche_dep_min = dep_time %% 100,
         sche_dep_exact_time = sche_dep_hour + sche_dep_min / 60)`
```

Code to plot:

```
`ggplot(data = flights_cancel_status) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x = sche_dep_exact_time,
                             y = cancel_status))`
```

The Error Message:

> Warning message:
> Removed 8255 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_boxplot()`).

I need a plot that sche_dep_exact_time is on the Aex X, and cancel_status on the Aex Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `cancel_status` as `ifelse(is.na(dep_time), "Y", "N")`. In other words, when `cancel_status` is `"Y"`, `dep_time` values were `NA`. So all your calculations based on `dep_time` are `NA` for entries where `cancel_status == "Y"`, including `sche_dep_exact_time`.

`ggplot2` removes `NA` entries, and this is why you get no `sche_dep_exact_time` boxplot for `cancel_status == "Y"`.